# jquery rebinding events with .on/.off

Tags: jquery, events

I'm currently sorting sections of the DOM by putting them into a array, running through sort and then appending them back into the DOM - this is working fine.

The issue I'm having is rebinding the required click events. This is a cut-down version of the DOM:

```
<div id="allmembers">

  <div id="member1">
    <img class="openmessage"/>
    <img class="deletemessage"/>
    <img class="pinmessage"/>
  </div>

  <div id="member2">
    <img class="openmessage"/>
    <img class="deletemessage"/>
    <img class="pinmessage"/>
  </div>

</div>
```

The sort/append occurs at the id= member1/member2 level so id="allmembers" doesn't move/change.

I did have click events in place like this for open/delete/pin class elements like:

```
$('#allmembers .openmessage).on('click', function(e) {
  alert('open message');
});
```

however this .on only works before the first sort/append. After it doesn't fire anymore.

How do I setup click events for elements that move (are no static) like this?

Comment: Where's your code that does the sorting?

Comment: You've got an unclosed quote at the end of your selector...

Comment: Is `$('#allmembers .openmessage)` a typo?  It's missing a quote?

Comment: yes I just typed it freehand and didn't test - just an example of the code... Answer below is perfect... thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try event delegation.

Attaching event to parent node and letting events from specific child nodes to be captured while bubling up.

heres the syntax:

```
$('#allmembers').on('click', '.openmessage', function(e) {
   alert('open message');
});
```

More info here: http://api.jquery.com/on/